# Prism.Forms : How to dispose the page that has been navigated from?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

[Xamarin.Forms]

I have a case where I am on the sign in page and after the user press sign in button I use the navigation service to go to the MainPage. The problem is that "LoginPage" is still active and receives and interacts with events, such as the login button would be pressed if I press "Enter" from the keyboard or the remove control . 
So is there a way to get rid of the "LoginPage" so it does not listen to  keyboard events (provided by default in Android) . 
Otherwise , is there a way to dispose the "LoginPage" After I navigate from it ?

Comment: Prism will destroy the view if registered as transient and implementing IDestructible. Check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127016/how-to-dispose-a-viewmodel-after-popping-a-page-with-xamarin-forms/60000910#60000910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating away from a view to another using Prism's INavigationService.NavigateAsync does not remove the page from the navigation stack.  It simply pushes another view onto the stack. Therefore it will not be GC'd.  You must remove the page from the navigation stack by either using an absolute URI when navigating, or to use XF's APIs to remove the page manually.

Comment: Thanks man an absolute Uri worked :) 
would be nice to improve that one from yours side guys, because having www.something.com/ViewAPage might not be the nicest thing ! But probably you have that in mind anyway .

Comment: Sorry, but that is the definition of an absolute URI.

Comment: @BrianLagunas navigationService.GoBackAsync() does not dispose page. Any reason not to dispose page on GoBackAsync?